# share website url on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Whenever i try to share website url on facebook only simple website url is shared, i was trying to share the description title and image of the shared post here is the code below

```
   <title><?php echo $sub; ?> | twekr</title>
   <meta property="og:url"           content="http://twekr.com
   /post/<?php echo $id; ?>" />

<meta property="og:type"     content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"    content="<?php echo $sub; ?> | twekr"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="twekr is a social job portal 
where people meet from far distance and find jobs related to fashion. 
here at we provide knitwear design, fashion design, Leather design, 
accessory design, fashion communication, textile design and much more" />
<meta property="og:image"    content="http://twekr.com/index/logo.png" />
```

now Whenever i share my website using this url
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A//twekr.com/post/ only url is shared nothing else

Comment: I tried to access the web page **http://twekr.com/post** but it redirect to 500 **http://twekr.com/oops.php?500**

Comment: are you trying to share url like this `http://twekr.com/post/1`

Comment: again error @DevendraBhandari check http://twekr.com/post/2 its fetching properly but not http://twekr.com/post/1

Comment: Its working debug the url here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Facebook Debugger to check what didn't work correctly:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Sometimes you need to use "Fetch new scrape information" in order to update the data for Facebook. And I think currently Facebook doesn't check the og:description.

I couldn't really test your URL since I would need a post ID for that.

Comment: A HTTP redirect
    A <link rel="canonical" href=".." /> tag
    A <meta property="og:url" content=".." /> tag this error i got what should i do now?

Comment: Where did you get the error? In the Facebook Debugger? Can you perhaps give me a full url I can test there? I.e. with a post id